# How can I cut down on the size of file loaded into Roo object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, csv, memory, roo-gem

I am using the `roo` gem to parse data in a CSV. The CSV is around 400MB in size however, and when I attempt to parse it with this loop...

```
(2..sheet.last_row).collect do |i|
   # parsing code...
end
```

It will error out with `[FATAL] failed to allocate memory`. I was going to break it up with smaller loops until it reaches the `last_row`, but just asking roo for the `last_row` will cause the error -- so I can't really tackle it that way.

Comment: You need to process it one line at a time, rather than loading the whole lot into a giant array and then iterating over the array.   I use FasterCSV which has a "process a file one line at a time" method.  Looking at roo on https://github.com/roo-rb/roo i can't see this functionality.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, thanks max. I'm also seeing that the Roo gem for this is limiting.  It appears it uses the ruby CSV library which from what I read is pretty outdated. I'm in the middle of exploring the `smarter-csv` gem and it appears to be handling the issue. Just a matter of redoing my work.